# Can't solve error with file including header that includes itself using header guards

Tags: c++

I have a header file named Application.h where I include a header named CollisionHandler.h. CollisionHandler includes Application.h, so I get a too many includes error when compiling. To solve this I've put the CollisionHandler include between header guards, like this:

```
#ifndef COLLISION_HANDLER_INCLUDED_H
#define COLLISION_HANDLER_INCLUDED_H
#include "CollisionHandler.h"
#endif
```

but when I try to use a object of type CollisionHandler (this class is defined in CollisionHandler.h, between header guards) as a member variable of the Application class (which is also defined between header guards in Application.h), I get this error repeated for every file that includes Application.h (5 times or so):

```
1>c:\users\aitor\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\copter\copter\application.h(19) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\aitor\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\copter\copter\application.h(19) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\aitor\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\copter\copter\application.h(19) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

The line 19 is the line where I declare the CollisionHandler object as a member variable.

Here is the code in Application.h (With the relevant lines idented):

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GameCharter.h"
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
    #ifndef COLLISION_HANDLER_INCLUDED_H //Here I include
    #define COLLISION_HANDLER_INCLUDED_H //the collision
    #include "CollisionHandler.h"        //handler header
    #endif
using namespace std;
#ifndef APPLICATION_DEFINED_H
#define APPLICATION_DEFINED_H
class LimitsManager;
class ObstacleManager;
class Application
{
public:
         CollisionHandler *handler; //Here I declare the CollisionHandler
    ObstacleManager *obstacleManager;
    LimitsManager *limitsManager;
    vector<boost::shared_ptr<GameChar> > characters;
    vector<int> idsToRemove;
    void gameLoop();
    Application();
    bool idsNeedUpdate;
    bool objectsNeedToRemove;
};
#endif
```

And this is the code for CollisionHandler.h:

```
#include "Header.h"
#include "Application.h" 
#include "GameCharter.h"
#include "LimitObstacle.h"
#ifndef COLLISION_HANDLER_H
#define COLLISION_HANDLER_H
class CollisionHandler
{
    Application *app;
public:
    void handleCollisions();
    CollisionHandler()
    {

    }
    CollisionHandler(Application *app);
    bool collidersAreCollidingGeneral(GameChar* char1,GameChar* char2);
    bool collidersAreCollidingSecondary(GameChar* char1,GameChar* char2);
};
#endif
```

Also, if I use `class CollisionHandler;` in Application.h and then include CollisionHandler.h in the cpp file, it works

Comment: Please show us the code you are talking about.

Comment: Two headers including each other doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth But Application needs info from CollisionHandler and CollisionHandler needs info from Application. I am using forward declarations to solve it, but I don't know why this doesn't work

Comment: @XaitormanX: You should find a way to break the cycle.  I don't know what you mean by "info", but perhaps you should put stuff that is needed by *both* headers into a third header, and have them both include that, rather than each other.

Comment: It works now with forward declaration and it seems to be the correct way to do it so i'll stick with that, but I thought header files would break the cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including headers cyclically is wrong, even with include guards.

Try to remove the dependency by using forward declarations where possible.

If you can't use forward declarations, your design is flawed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was using forward declarations to solve it, but I wanted to know why this doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

all you need to do is add/write

```
pragma once
```

at the top of each header file

Comment: Note that although this is widely supported, it is non-standard and thus makes your code less portable.